# error 17054 severity 16 state 1 sql server 2014 enterprise edition

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2014

Our new database is just inaccessible.
I have tried to find it in the error log and find this error during that time. So when we went to the Configuration manager. we were seeing Browser service, SQL Agent, and SQL Server services were stopped, and then tried to restart it just hung and because of that, I have to do a reboot. It is a production server and this is a recurring issue. It happened a month ago and last week it happened and also it happened today.
So my DBA has repaired the SQL instance to make the server operation. I am not seeing any issue with database integrity though but I could not find the resolution yet. 
This is a SharePoint database.
Do you have this kind of situation? How did you solve that?

[image: SQL Server log during the time of SQL server inaccessible]

Comment: Vote to close - off you go: dba.stackexchange.com, Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community - more specific than serverfault which is like a "all that has no other more specific place". Databases are a large field, having their own site.

Comment: would not a vote for movement a better choice?